# QDataStream not initialized while reading buffer from ipc fifo file descriptor

Tags: qt, ipc, fifo, mkfifo, qdatastream

I want to communicate between two application using fifo (ipc), I have created a fifo by "mkfifo MyPipe" command.

first App:

```
....
....
fd = open("MyPipe", O_NONBLOCK | O_WRONLY);

QByteArray buf;
QDataStream bdwr(&buf,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
bdwr.setVersion(kDSVersion);

myclassObjWr.lname = "AAAAA";
myclassObjWr.fname = "BBBBB";

bdwr << myclassObjWr.lname << myclassObjWr.fname ;

ssize_t written = write(fd,buf.data() , buf.length());

.....
.....
```

second App:

```
....
....
fd = open("MyPipe", O_NONBLOCK | O_RDONLY);
ssize_t nread;
QByteArray rxbuf;
static const QDataStream::Version kDSVersion = QDataStream::Qt_5_12;
QDataStream bdrd(&rxbuf, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
bdrd.setVersion(kDSVersion);

nread = read(fd, rxbuf.data(),200);

if ( nread > 0)
{
    bdrd.writeRawData(rxbuf.data(),nread);
    bdrd >> myclassObjrd.lname >> myclassObjrd.fname;  
    qDebug() << "lname: " << myclassObjrd.lname;
}
....
```

## ....

After reading the ipc fifo the "rxbuf" is initialized completely but "myclassObjrd.lname" and  "myclassObjrd.fname" both are empty and do not initialize.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by using an intermediate unsigned char buffer to initialize QByteArray in the Second App as follows.

```
# ...
ssize_t nread;

QByteArray buf;

unsigned char* rxbuf;

static const QDataStream::Version kDSVersion = QDataStream::Qt_5_12;

QDataStream bdrd(&buf, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

bdrd.setVersion(kDSVersion);

rxbuf = (unsigned char*)malloc(200);

nread = read(fd, rxbuf,200);

if ( nread > 0)
{

   for (int i = 0 ; i < nread; i++) {

   buf[i] = rxbuf[i] ;   //init QByteArray

   }

bdrd >> myclassObjrd.lname >> myclassObjrd.fname;  

qDebug() << "lname: " << myclassObjrd.lname;

}
# ...
```